# Can Docker work targeting any arch with Windows 10 ARM?

Tags: docker, arm, windows-10-iot-core

I'd like to know if I'll be able to run Docker on ARM (Windows) machine and still have the same versatility?

I didn't see a lot of readings about this, as ARM PCs are quite new.

Comment: ARM "PCs" recent? Not really. Linux folks have been playing with those for years.

Comment: Microsoft made an [ARM-based Windows Surface machine in 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(2012_tablet)). ARM-based machines have been around even longer, though the 2012 introduction of the Rasperry Pi popularized it.

Comment: May i know you were talking about  docker running on Windows IoT Core ARM-based? Docker does not support Windows IoT Core ARM at the moment.